# angular-meteor 1.3 $meteor.object the new way

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

There is something I'm probably missing but I try to access a single document from  my mongo collection Tribunaux reactively without $stateParams in my variable modifTrib. I got the tribunalId field when I clicked on a button. So before I click my variable is null in my controller.

Here is what I did :

```js
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('tribunauxController', tribunauxController);

tribunauxController.$inject = ['$scope', '$reactive', '$mdDialog'];

function tribunauxController($scope, $reactive, $mdDialog)
{
    $reactive(this).attach($scope);
    var vm = this;
    vm.TribunalModify = TribunalModify;
    vm.tribunalId = null;


     vm.helpers({
        tribunaux: () => {
            return Tribunaux.find({});
        }
    });

    vm.helpers({
        modifTrib () {
            return Tribunaux.findOne(tribunalId);
        }
    });


    function TribunalModify(tribId){
        vm.tribunalId = tribId;
    }                                                                    }
```

I can't get this to work.

Need a little help thanks!

**UPDATE : Here is the interesting part of my HTML**

```
<md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-click="vm.TribunalModify(tribunal._id)"
                              ng-repeat="tribunal in vm.tribunaux">
        <div class="md-list-item-text">
            <h3>Tribunal d'instance de {{tribunal.label}}</h3>
            <p>{{tribunal.address}}</p>
        </div>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: Can you show your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change 2 things:

1. Merge the `helpers` into one helpers definition (I think it's just looks nicer)
2. `tribunalId` has to be reactively in order to make the helper re-run. there are few ways of doing that (we are just discussing it here: https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/955) but for now, the easiest way is to use `getReactively` like that:

   return Tribunaux.findOne(getReactively("tribunalId"));

Comment: Thanks with your answer here is the line I wrote :

`return Tribunaux.findOne($scope.getReactively("vm.tribunalId"));`

with that I can find my object but when I modify it, it doesn't update in mongo..

So for now I'll stay with that 
`vm.modifTrib = $scope.$meteorObject(Tribunaux, {_id: tribId});`

Comment: If you want to modify that you will need to create an update function and update it explicitly. it's better then using `autobind`.

Comment: Try the new 1.3.1, we've fixed some things related to that and also added a lot to the docs

Comment: this is my line : modifTrib: () => Tribunaux.find({ _id: this.getReactively('tribunalId') }) I wrote it with this : angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.1/helpers Shouldn't be findOne instead of find ?